# MC who is reincarnated makes a high grade healing potion

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai, reincarnation, cultivation

When the main character was reincarnated, I believe he was a teenager and was also an adventurer. I remember a manga where the main character made a healing potion from regular flowers and grass to embarrass a noble, because the noble had to use rare ingredients to make a high-grade healing potion when the main character only used grass and flowers to make it.

The other part I remember is that he was invited  to a party by a female noble because he was good at making potions. The manga was in black and white.

I read it a year ago. I don't remember the name, only some of it. He made a high-grade healing potion from regular grass and flowers to embarrass nobles for using high class ingredients. He was a commoner. He would use pills to increase his cultivation to become strong and to protect his little sister. It took place in a sect.

Comment: Remember to refer to the [story ID checklist](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and see if you can add anything useful for those who would answer.

Comment: Was the MC a commoner, or a low-ranking aristocrat? Do you remember how this noble and the MC were brought together? For example, did the story take place at a school for nobility? Was he an adventurer and travelling with this arrogant noble? Did the MC have powers specific to healing / potion making, or was he just overpowered in general?

Comment: he was a commoner he would use pills to increase his cultivation to become strong and to protect his little sister it took place in a sect

Comment: Ah, I was going to point out *Cheat Kusushi no Slow Life: Isekai ni Tsukurou Drugstore*, which has the "superior potion from plants and stems", but it's not cultivation or sect.

Comment: Could you explicitly rule out *Cheat Kusushi no Slow Life* from FuzzyBoots' suggestion? Additionally, you mention that it's black&white, but also a cultivation story. Is it possible you're mixing up two different stories? My experience is that most (not all, but close) cultivation stories are full-color manhua

Answer (score -1):

Found it. is it maybe Apotheosis?

Comment: Please describe this work and how it matches the details in the question.

Comment: This one? https://apotheosis-manga.fandom.com/wiki/Apotheosis_Wiki