Manga/manhwa where the strongest mage dies after demons kill all people and is reincarnated as a child few years back
Just found it! It was The Tales of Demons and Gods Thank you everyone for help
I think it was a manhwa. It’s fantasy, so there is magic. It’s like medieval.
The hero dies after battling with demons and is reincarnated back in time to his kid-self. He has his past memories, but not his powers. He then decides that he will get even stronger and helps people around get to get stronger too, so in the future demons don't win like it already happened.
For example: he knows how to make a sort of potion from some grass that boosts your magic power. He buys all the grass and after that he reveals the recipe for said potion. Now he has all the grass that is really expensive because it is needed for the potions.
It was coloured, and I read it at least 5 years back, but I am not really sure when unfortunately.

When did you read it / how old is it? Color or B&W? ANY other details would be helpful.

Doesn't seem like a good match after re-reading it, but the mention of making a potion from grass made me think of this question - https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/261340 - Any chance this is the same story? There's an answer but with no details so it's hard to tell if it fits.

No it was not a healing potion. I read this post too, but unoftunately it isnt the one

I think it's A Returner's Magic Should Be Special:

Ten years ago, the world became a Shadow World that resulted in the death of the majority of the world's inhabitants. To save the world, 150 million mages entered the Shadow Labyrinth to clear it, but only six remain. The remaining mages finally defeat the dungeon boss Boromir Napolitan. After the battle, the six reflect on their adventure. However, the dragon's heart suddenly explodes, releasing the tremendous amount of mana it stored to destroy the world and kill the remaining mages. One of the last six, Desir Herrman, finds himself returning 13 years into the past right before the Hebrion Academy entrance ceremony.

It ticks off all the characteristics - Hero dies when battling demons, reincarnates to his younger self and using his memories of previous life starts working on himself getting better and assisting his friends to do the same to avert the disaster.
Not a bad show, I must admit.

Hi, thank you. I looked into it and unfortunatelly, this aint the one a remember. Mine was more colourful and probably a mnhwa, it was a bit different style os art then this one. I will look into this one too how ever. It looks interesting.

I just found it. It was the Tales ofDemons and Gods. Thank you very moch for your help thou!
